# Superimposing two or more subsets in same plot

Tags: r, plot, subset, frequency, density-plot

I'm trying to visualize a 3 level subset of my data in one figure for two different treatments.

I want to visualize the distribution of age for only 1 year (2007), for only one item (tattoo), and for females and males separately.

I am able to reduce my dataset to only females, only in 2007, and only for tattoos using:

```
with(data[(data$sex=="F") & (data$yy=="2007") & (data$item=="tattoo"),], plot(age, xlab="Age of Females", ylab="Frequency"))
```

With this code, I am able to see a frequency distribution of my data.
[image: 3 tier subset]

But, I am unable, using that code, to do two things:

1. visualize the data as a density plot
2. superimpose the multiple tier subset for males

The closest I've been able to come is using this code:

```
library(sm)
sm.density.compare(age, sex, xlab="Age (years)")
legend(50,0.12, c("Female","Male"), col=c("red", "green"), pch=c(16,16), title="Sex", box.lty=0)
```

It gives this figure:
[image: Density plot]

But, with this code, I am unable to get the data to be restricted to the year 2007 and only tattoos.

My question is two fold:

1. Is it possible to superimpose the male data (for 2007 and tattoos) on the female frequency data?
2. How can I restrict the density data to only 2007 and tattoos?

I have made a subset of my data available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

UPDATE: For the frequency histogram, I am trying to visualize the data with the bars for female and male adjacent to each other for each bin.

Comment: To get the density plot use `plot(density(your_data_subset))`. If you want to add additional density plots use `lines`, for example :`lines(density(your_second_data_subset))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard R plotting you can do as follows

```
with(data[(data$sex=="F") & (data$yy=="2007") & (data$item=="tattoo"),], plot(density(age)))
with(data[(data$sex=="M") & (data$yy=="2007") & (data$item=="tattoo"),], lines(density(age), col = "red"))
segments(50,0.1,52,0.1, col = "black")
text(52,0.1, pos = 4, labels = "Female")
segments(50,0.09,52,0.09, col = "red")
text(52,0.09, pos = 4, labels = "Male")
```

[image]

A smooth alternative is to use ggplot2 and the easyGgplot2 package by *kassambara*

```
library(devtools)
install_github("kassambara/easyGgplot2")
library(easyGgplot2)
library(ggplot2)
my.subset <- data[(data$yy=="2007") & (data$item=="tattoo"),]
ggplot2.histogram(data=my.subset, xName='age',binwidth = 2,
                  groupName='sex', legendPosition="top",
                  alpha=0.5, position="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to run the first line you suggested, the error I get is: Error in density.default(age) : argument 'x' must be numeric

Comment: read your data this way `data <- read.delim("data30g.txt", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: That solved the problem! Your answer for part 2 of my question worked. Might you have any suggestions about part 1 (frequency plot) of my question?

Comment: I suggested an alternative that is ggplot2-based. Hope that could be useful.

Comment: I am still learning how to use the ggplot function. But, this is a great place for me to start from. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure you can do this using the *ggplot2.histogram()* function, since it only works with continuous x variables. Let me have a look at it though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152668/discussion-between-blundering-ecologist-and-damiano-fantini).

Answer (score 1):

Use `density` to get density plots and `lines` to add a second or more density plots

```
plot(density(data[data$sex=="F" & data$yy=="2007" & data$item=="tattoo" ,]), col="red")
lines(density(data[data$sex=="M" & data$yy=="2007" & data$item=="tattoo" ,]), col="green")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest subsetting the data by 2007 and tattoo before you plot.

```
date <- c(rep(2006-07-15,7),rep(2007-07-15,14))
yy <- c(rep(2006,7), rep(2007,14))
sex <- c(rep("F",4),"M", "M",rep("F",4),rep("M",4),rep("F",3),rep("M",4))
item <- c(rep("piercing",8), rep("tattoo",5), "jewel",rep("tattoo",7))
age <- c(rep(22,8), rep(25,3), rep(34,2), 41, 37,rep(28,2), rep(31,3), 39)

df <- data.frame(date,yy,sex,item,age)
df2 <- subset(df, df$yy == 2007 & df$item == "tattoo")


d <- density(df2$age[df2$sex=='F'])
plot(d, main="Density", xlab="Age", col="red")
lines(density(df2$age[df2$sex=='M']), col="blue")

legend("topright", legend=c("Female","Male"), col=c("red","blue"), lty=c(1,1), title="Sex")
```

[image]

If you wanted to overlay the histogram plots instead, you can use this:

```
hist(df2$age[df2$sex=='F'], col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5), main="Histogram", xlab="Age")
hist(df2$age[df2$sex=='M'], col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5), add=T)
```

[image]

If you want to get the histograms side by side, it is slightly more complicated in base R. Here is some code:

```
breaks <- pretty(range(c(df2$age[df2$sex=='F'], df2$age[df2$sex=='M'])), n=10)
h1 <- hist(df2$age[df2$sex=='F'], breaks=breaks, plot=F)$counts
h2 <- hist(df2$age[df2$sex=='M'], breaks=breaks, plot=F)$counts
new_h <- rbind(h1,h2)
colnames(new_h) <- paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep="-")

barplot(new_h, beside=TRUE, main="Histogram", xlab="Age")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how to run my code without having to restrict it to 40 years old, as you've done here. When I try to run the code without limiting the data as you've done, I get an error about the arguement 'x' not being numeric. Also, for the histogram, is it possible to plot the bins adjacent to each other, rather than on top of each other?

Comment: I used sample data (so no restriction to 40 years old). You should check that age is numeric in your dataframe. Yes, it is possible to get them beside. I will edit my response to show that code.

Comment: Thanks for editing your response to show that. I will give that a try too!